# Failure ONNX InferenceSession ONNX model exported from PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, onnx, onnxruntime

I am trying to export a custom PyTorch model to ONNX to perform inference but without success... The tricky thing here is that I'm trying to use the *script-based exporter* as shown in the example [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/onnx.html#tracing-vs-scripting) in order to call a function from my model.

I can export the model without any complain but then when trying to start an `InferenceSession` I get the following error:

```
Fail: [ONNXRuntimeError] : 1 : FAIL : Load model from ner.onnx failed:Type Error: Type parameter (T) bound to different types (tensor(int64) and tensor(float) in node (Concat_1260).
```

I tried to identify the root cause of that problem and it seems to be generated by the use of `torch.matmul()` in the following function (quite nasty cause I'm trying to only use pytorch operators):

```
@torch.jit.script
def valid_sequence_output(sequence_output, valid_mask):
    X = torch.where(valid_mask.unsqueeze(-1) == 1, sequence_output, torch.zeros_like(sequence_output))
    bs, max_len, _ = X.shape

    tu = torch.unique(torch.nonzero(X)[:, :2], dim=0)
    batch_axis = tu[:, 0]
    rows_axis = tu[:, 1]

    a = torch.arange(bs).repeat(batch_axis.shape).reshape(batch_axis.shape[0], -1)
    a = torch.transpose(a, 0, 1)

    T = torch.cumsum(torch.where(batch_axis == a, torch.ones_like(a), torch.zeros_like(a)), dim=1) - 1
    cols_axis = T[batch_axis, torch.arange(batch_axis.shape[0])]

    A = torch.zeros((bs, max_len, max_len))
    A[(batch_axis, cols_axis, rows_axis)] = 1.0

    valid_output = torch.matmul(A, X)
    valid_attention_mask = torch.where(valid_output[:, :, 0] != 0, torch.ones_like(valid_mask),
                                       torch.zeros_like(valid_mask))
    return valid_output, valid_attention_mask
```

It seems like `torch.matmul` isn't supported (according to the docs) so I tried a bunch of workaround (e.g. `A.matmul(X)`, `torch.baddbmm`) but I still get the same issue...

Any suggestions on how to fix this behavior would be awesome :D
Thanks for your help!

Comment: try torch.jit.trace() and export to onnx

Answer (score 0):

This points to a model conversion issue. Please open an issue againt the Torch exporter feature. A type (T) has to be bound to the same type for the model to be valid and ORT is basically complaining about this.